# werkzeug WSGI only reachable via "localhost"

Tags: python, macos, flask, werkzeug

I'm having a weird issue testing my flask app.
I reduced it to the following, let this be 'test.py':

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from flask import Flask

    app = Flask(__name__)
    @app.route('/hello')
    def hello():
        return 'hello\n'

    app.run(debug = True)
```

So I simply run this as:

```
python test.py 
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
```

Now on another terminal I can do this:

```
>> curl http://localhost:5000/hello
hello
```

However, what does not work, is this:

```
>> curl http://192.168.178.23:5000/hello
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

Where `ifconfig en1` gives:
    `[...] inet 192.168.178.23 [...]`

Originally I'd like to test my actual app from another machine within the local network - that's how I came across this issue.

I also tried with my browser, wget and other "clients".

If I replace all the Flask/Werkzeug stuff with the python builtin BaseHTTPServer & Handler, things are fine - which lets me conclude that there's some weird issue going on with flask or werkzeug underneath, rather than e.g. with my network configuration.

I'm not too familiar with all low-level io, so don't really know where to start looking the for the source of the problem.

Apologies in advance, if I'm missing something stupid here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, Flask listens only on your loopback interface, as exposing the debug interface (which allows execution of arbitrary Python code) to other machines is a serious security risk. To override this, try:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

However, make sure your system is appropriately shielded from untrusted machines.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply - this seems to do the trick. When you say "debug mode", this only applies to running the app via `app.run`?! Because things don't seem to change with `debug = False`. I seem to remember having accessed flask-apps running this way on a debian machine from other machines in the local network. I might remember wrong though...

Comment: I think you're right, the debug thing is separate from the default host.